# How can i hold down a key (shift) and perform an action (click)

Tags: javascript, protractor

I'm trying to test functionality with protractor where when you hold down shift and click an element it adds to the selected elements (vs no shift).

My first try was this

```js
    await browser.actions()
      .keyDown(protractor.Key.SHIFT)
      .mouseMove(await element(by.css('#datagrid .datagrid-wrapper tbody tr:nth-child(9) td:nth-child(1)')))
      .click()
      .perform();
```

This acts exactly click the shift action isnt being held down. also tried things like this

```
await browser.actions().mouseMove(elem).keyDown(protractor.Key.SHIFT);
await elem.click();
```

This also did not work. Is there a special trick to make holding a key down while clicking work?
Or maybe some problem with shift in general?

Comment: It looks to me like maybe you should be using `.sendKeys()` in place of `.keyDown()` https://www.protractortest.org/#/api?view=webdriver.WebElement.prototype.sendKeys

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the below option

```
await browser.actions().sendKeys(protractor.Key.SHIFT).perform().then(async () =>{
await browser.actions().mouseMove(await element(by.css('#datagrid .datagrid-wrapper tbody tr:nth-child(9) td:nth-child(1)'))).click().perform();
});
```

Hope it helps you

Comment: This did work, thank you. Ended up using a slight variant..


`const elem = await element(by.css('#datagrid .datagrid-wrapper tbody tr:nth-child(9) td:nth-child(1)'));

    // Simulate Shift + Click
    await browser.actions().sendKeys(protractor.Key.SHIFT).perform().then(async () => {
      await elem.click();

      expect(await element.all(by.css('.datagrid-row.is-selected')).count()).toEqual(4);
    });`

Comment: @Tim it shouldn't be required to use the `.then` when you are already using `await`. It would be worth removing that and trying again for simplicity

Comment: @DublinDev I have used `.then()`  to keep hold of `SHIFT` Key. Anyways thanks for your inputs.

Comment: @Tim `.then` simply enforces a wait until your `browser.actions().sendKeys(protractor.Key.SHIFT).perform()` promise has resolved which should already be taken care of with your `await`. I would encourage you to try it with this instead and would expect to see the same behavior `const elem = await element(by.css('#datagrid .datagrid-wrapper tbody tr:nth-child(9) td:nth-child(1)')); 
// Simulate Shift + Click 
await browser.actions().sendKeys(protractor.Key.SHIFT).perform();
await elem.click(); expect(await element.all(by.css('.datagrid-row.is-selected')).count()).toEqual(4);`

Comment: The then was the only way it would every work for me. Otherwise it was as if shift wasnt down